# PHP Source Code "Mapping"

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone knew of a program that could accept a directory of php files and analyze them so that every function, variable, etc. has links to where it is defined, referenced, etc. so that I can quickly determine the purpose/use of a function. I know that RIPS does something similiar to this but it is primarily a vulnerability analysis tool. I would prefer not to have to pay for it if possible.

Comment: In addition to the below answers, you may want to consider using an IDE that lets you navigate to where a function is defined using a simple keystroke...e.g. in NetBeans you can press Ctrl/Cmd+B, in Eclipse or Aptana you can press F3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) can analyze files in that manner.

Comment: On second thought, I was thinking of Cscope, which only supports C, not PHP. Nevertheless, Exuberant Ctags will find definitions; just not references.

Answer (score 0):

IDEs like [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) provide this kind of feature, but inline as you are editing, not by generating a separate map file. You can right-click on a function and go to where it is defined, for example, or click on a defined function and find all the places it is used.